# Adding an integer to data, but plots a real

Tags: python, pyqt4, pyqtgraph

I have a function that looks like this. I am adding integers like 940320 to the data. What is interesting is that the `print` statement correctly shows that it is an int. But then the graph seems to force two decimal points to the graph?! What is maddening is that it **used** to show the data as integers, but it has stopped working even though I don't think I have made any change that could cause this!

One clue I am noticing is that the plot labels used to have (s) at the end of the name, e.g., Symbol1(s). But now for some reason they say (ks) at the end. I have no idea what this does.

In any event, is there a way for force pyqtgraph to plot an int and not whatever it thinks the precision of the number is?

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui

import numpy as np

win = pg.GraphicsWindow()
win.setWindowTitle('Scrolling Plots')
win.showMaximized()

# 1) Simplest approach -- update data in the array such that plot appears to scroll
#    In these examples, the array size is fixed.
p1 = win.addPlot()
p2 = win.addPlot()

p1.setLabel('left', 'Symbol1', 's')
p2.setLabel('left', 'Symbol2', 's')

data1 = []
data2 = []
data3 = []
data4 = []

curve1 = p1.plot(data1)
curve2 = p2.plot(data2)

win.nextRow()

p3 = win.addPlot()
p4 = win.addPlot()

p3.setLabel('left', 'Symbol3', 's')
p4.setLabel('left', 'Symbol4', 's')

curve3 = p3.plot(data3)
curve4 = p4.plot(data4)

def update1(data):
    global data1, curve1, ptr1
    print "Got symbol 1 ", data

    if data1:
       data1[:-1] = data1[1:]  # shift data in the array one sample left
                                # (see also: np.roll)
    data1.append(data)
    curve1.setData(data1)

    ptr1 += 1
    QtGui.QApplication.instance().processEvents()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

**EDIT:**

Even if I say `data1.append(int(data))` same behavior

**EDIT 1:**

Adding data like 0.92345 will shift the graphs to (ms) and also forces the data to be displayed as 923.45

So trying to graph integers, and trying to graph doubles less than 1 appears to have strange behavior.

Comment: Can you be more clear what "the graph seems to force two decimal points to the graph" means? Are the points showing up in the wrong place? Are the axis labels wrong? It would help to post an example that 1) immediately shows the incorrect behavior, and 2) executes (don't make us debug your example).

Comment: Is there a way to post an image on here?

Comment: If I add 9.43456, it displays correctly in the graph, and the axis make sense given the number that are going in. If I input 0.94356, it FORCES the numbers in the graph to be 943.56, and the axis make sense for THAT number. What is strange is that right before I add the number, I print to the console what number I am adding, and it is correct. It is something weird about the graphing itself that is doing this. If I add 943560, it also forces 943.56. If I add ints, the graph shows (ks). If add numbers like 0.9 it shows (ms). Only if I add doubles >= 1, the graph shows what I asked for, (s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AxisItem` automatically scales its units if you provide a unit string. When you write

`p3.setLabel('left', 'Symbol3', 's')`,

you are telling the `AxisItem` that the data for this axis has units of 's', and it will automatically apply an SI prefix to keep the tick labels small. So if your values went from 0 to 0.0001, then the axis values will be displayed as 0 to 100 and the units will be 'µs' (because 0.0001 s is the same as 100 µs).

If you don't want this behavior, then just omit the units argument:

`p3.setLabel('left', 'Symbol3 (s)')`

Comment: tada! Thank you. BTW, why the extra (s) after Symbol3? I just wrote Symbol and it seems to work.

Comment: One more question, if Instead of displaying say 1.2445 for the axis, I actually want it to show me the zero, 1.24450 how do I tell it how many symbols of precision to display? In other words, I want the axis to always be a certain number of precision and pad with zeroes if the number is too small. That way I don't get some lables being two number long and the rest 3, etc.

Comment: It's just a string to be displayed in the axis label; I assumed you wanted the (s) there. Any string is allowed. To change the tick strings, you'll need to make an `AxisItem` subclass and override ``tickStrings()`. The default implementation is pretty simple: https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/blob/develop/pyqtgraph/graphicsItems/AxisItem.py#L736

Answer (score 0):

I am taking a look at it, I have however already corrected some errors such as forgetting to instantiate QtGui.QApplication with sys.argv.

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui
QtApp = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)


win = pg.GraphicsWindow()
win.setWindowTitle('Scrolling Plots')
win.showMaximized()

# 1) Simplest approach -- update data in the array such that plot appears to scroll
#    In these examples, the array size is fixed.
p1 = win.addPlot()
p2 = win.addPlot()

p1.setLabel('left', 'Symbol1', 's')
p2.setLabel('left', 'Symbol2', 's')

data1 = []
data2 = []
data3 = []
data4 = []

curve1 = p1.plot(data1)

def update1(data):
    global data1, curve1, ptr1
    print "Got symbol 1 ", data

    if data1:
        data1[:-1] = data1[1:]  # shift data in the array one sample left
        # (see also: np.roll)
    data1.append(data)
    curve1.setData(data1)

    ptr1 += 1
    QtApp.instance().processEvents()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtApp.instance().exec_()
```

Comment: Thanks. However none of those things make a difference.

Comment: I'll get back with an answer soon hopefully.

Comment: I added a little more code to my post...shouldn't make a difference